# Bash shell is locked after running script

Tags: bash, shell

I made my own script to make testing a little faster to execute on my .NET projects.

The name of the script is TestCoverage and is located in /home/user/bin folder with executable permissions and also added to my PATH for convenience.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Collecting TestCoverage..."

dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover
```

The script runs as expected but after it's done the terminal stops taking input. I can only press the Enter key and the cursor is blinking as usual.

Bash version 4.4.20 running on Ubuntu 18.04

I've made some testing and it seems to take input but it isn't showed to the console. The problem is not consistent, it comes and goes through different terminal sessions.

Comment: Are you sure that `dotnet` exits at that time? or if it is still running in the background? Does the process exit?

Comment: I can run ps in that terminal and your suspicions are correct. The process has not finished. Why is that? Shouldn't my script run til end before giving back control?

Comment: `dotnet` executes a test with few input files, but `dotnet` seems to not exit clearly or gets stuck at something .. or is not doing proper garbage-collection before exit.. but this issue is that it does not exit, or is not really done, in order to exit

Answer (score 0):

Your script (and likely the `dotnet` process it invokes, because `echo` is a shell intrinsic that usually returns within milliseconds) is probably still running and hasn't returned.

You can open another console and type `ps aux -H` to view the running processes - look out for some adjacent lines with `TestCoverage`, `bash`, and `dotnet`.
In those lines, you can see what state the process(es) are in
([RTM](https://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/1/ps/) for further detail).

If you are running a console under X, you can first look around whether you accidentally pushed some running `dotnet test ...` window behind your console window. :-)

Comment: It's seems to be when I interupt the script with a key press during the "echo" execution.

Comment: Maybe it's because I accidentaly hold the Enter key a little longer some times? Any ideas to work around this?

Comment: The "echo" itself is not interactive, so this doesn't seem plausible to me.